# How to include more dates on my x axis

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, date, axis

I’m having issue to include additional dates on my x axis.
Usually I’d select data, edit my horizontal axis label to include more dates. (2nd pic) But it’s not showing up on my graph. (1st pic) I also checked to format my axis. Before I was able to change the maximum the date, however when I click to format my date axis, my graph changes. (3rd pic)
Does anyone know how to fix this?

[Date not showing on x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sZ3a.png)

[select data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmXSZ.png)

[format date axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl9NK.png)

Answer (score 0):

The earlier dates need to be formatted as dated instead of entered as simply the year, so you would need to turn 2000 into 1/1/2000.